# Retrieve data from a website via Visual Basic

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

There is this website that we purchase widgets from that provides details for each of their parts on its own webpage. Example: http://www.digikey.ca/product-search/en?lang=en&site=ca&KeyWords=AE9912-ND. I have to find all of their parts that are in our database, and add Manufacturer and Manufacturer Part Number values to their fields.

I was told that there is a way for Visual Basic to access a  webpage and extract information. If someone could point me in the right direction on where to start, I'm sure I can figure this out.

Thanks.

Comment: ... Look into `HttpWebRequest` / `HttpWebResponse` to create your own program or http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ - Hope this helps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### How to scrape a website using HTMLAgilityPack (VB.Net)

I agree that [htmlagilitypack](http://html-agility-pack.net) is the easiest way to accomplish this. It is less error prone than just using Regex. The following will be how I deal with scraping.

<strike>After downloading htmlagilitypack*dll</strike>, create a new application, add *htmlagilitypack* via nuget, and reference to it. If you can use Chrome, it will allow you to inspect the page to get information about where your information is located. Right-click on a value you wish to capture and look for the table that it is found in (follow the HTML up a bit).

The following example will extract all the values from that page within the "pricing" table. We need to know the [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp) value for the table (this value is used to instruct htmlagilitypack on what to look for) so that the document we create looks for our specific values. This can be achieved by finding whatever structure your values are in and right click copy XPath. From this we get...

```
//*[@id="pricing"]
```

Please note that sometimes the XPath you get from Chrome may be rather large. You can often simplify it by finding something unique about the table your values are in. In this example it is "id", but in other situations, it could easily be headings or class or whatever.

This XPath value looks for something with the id equal to pricing, that is our table. When we look further in, we see that our values are within tbody,tr and td tags. HtmlAgilitypack doesn't work well with the tbody so ignore it. Our new XPath is...

```
//*[@id='pricing']/tr/td
```

This XPath says look for the pricing id within the page, then look for text within its tr and td tags. Now we add the code...

```
Dim Web As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb
Dim Doc As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
Doc = Web.Load("http://www.digikey.ca/product-search/en?lang=en&site=ca&KeyWords=AE9912-ND")
For Each table As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode In Doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id='pricing']/tr/td")

Next
```

To extract the values we simply reference our table value that was created in our loop and it's innertext member.

```
Dim Web As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb
Dim Doc As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
Doc = Web.Load("http://www.digikey.ca/product-search/en?lang=en&site=ca&KeyWords=AE9912-ND")
For Each table As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode In Doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id='pricing']/tr/td")
    MsgBox(table.InnerText)
Next
```

Now we have message boxes that pop up the values...you can switch the message box for an arraylist to fill or whatever way you wish to store the values. Now simply do the same for whatever other tables you wish to get.

Please note that the Doc variable that was created is reusable, so if you wanted to cycle through a different table in the same page, you do not have to reload the page. This is a good idea especially if you are making many requests, you don't want to slam the website, and if you are automating a large number of scrapes, it puts some time between requests.

Scraping is really that easy. That's is the basic idea. Have fun!

Comment: Hi there thanks for spending so much time helping me out. The only problem is that none of the tags outside of the value have any IDs so I can't really use SelectNodes.

Comment: Ok here goes. As for finding a value that has no decernable identifier try this. highlight the "1" in the price break column of the page you listed in your initial question. right click and inspect element. You will see highlighted html below, right click and copy xpath. Take that and paste it into notepad, it should look like //*[@id="pricing"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1] to be continued.

Comment: <span itemprop="name">Assmann WSW Components</span> I want to retrieve the value, but I can't seem to use itemprop like the way you use id. I also don't see the xpath that starts with //*

Comment: you will notice that the text we got has some array index notation. This is the actual location within its structure...by changing these values you get other areas of the table. Now remove the tbody since it will not return results, paste it into your select nodes and change the " to '

Comment: to get the name   "//span[@itemprop='name']"

Comment: HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb Web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument Doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
Doc = Web.Load("http://www.digikey.ca/product-search/en?lang=en&site=ca&KeyWords=AE9912-ND");
foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode table in Doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@itemprop='url']")) {
 Interaction.MsgBox(table.InnerText);
}

Answer (score 0):

[Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) is going to be your friend!

> **What is exactly the Html Agility Pack (HAP)?**
>
> This is an agile HTML parser that builds a read/write DOM and supports
>   plain XPATH or XSLT (you actually don't HAVE to understand XPATH nor
>   XSLT to use it, don't worry...). It is a .NET code library that allows
>   you to parse "out of the web" HTML files. The parser is very tolerant
>   with "real world" malformed HTML. The object model is very similar to
>   what proposes System.Xml, but for HTML documents (or streams).

Looking at the source of the example page you provided, they are using HTML5 Microdata in their markup. I searched some more on `CodePlex` and found a microdata parser which may help too: [MicroData Parser](http://microdata.codeplex.com/)